# What are the list of characters XSLT escapes while producing string values?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I know that setting disable-output-escaping attribute to true, we can escape certain special characters. Is there any list somewhere?
XSLT Version: 1.0
Implementation I'm using: Xalan XSLT 1.0

Comment: Do you mean this? https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

`disable-output-escaping` prevents the escaping of characters that would otherwise to be escaped according to the output method. With `xsl:output method="html"` the XSLT processor is supposed to serialize according to HTML rules, with output method `xml` according to XML rules.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#disable-output-escaping:

> Normally, the xml output method escapes `&` and `<` (and possibly other
> characters) when outputting text nodes. This ensures that the output
> is well-formed XML. However, it is sometimes convenient to be able to
> produce output that is almost, but not quite well-formed XML; for
> example, the output may include ill-formed sections which are intended
> to be transformed into well-formed XML by a subsequent non-XML aware
> process. For this reason, XSLT provides a mechanism for disabling
> output escaping. An `xsl:value-of` or `xsl:text` element may have a
> disable-output-escaping attribute; the allowed values are yes or no;
> the default is no; if the value is yes, then a text node generated by
> instantiating the xsl:value-of or xsl:text element should be output
> without any escaping. For example,
>
> `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>` should
> generate the single character `<`.

As for a definite list, for consistency `>` is often escaped as `&gt;` but you would have to test with a particular version of a particular processor whether it does that, for Xalan Java it seems https://github.com/apache/xalan-j/blob/trunk/src/org/apache/xml/serializer/CharInfo.java with related files is doing the escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer martin. I went through the documentation multiple times, but I'm in need of a defined characters list which gets escaped. I'm going through the xslt processor code as well, but no luck so far.

Comment: As I said, that depends on the various factors like the output method, as well as on the output encoding. For XML rules `<` needs to be escaped as `&lt;`, `&` as `&amp;`, `>` is usually escaped as `&gt;`. But an `ä` might be escaped as `&#228;` with e.g. `xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"`. Or it could ube escaped using a hexadecimal numeric character reference.

Comment: Also the list of characters that are escaped is different for attributes and text nodes.